# Input file empty after upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, blueimp

I am using some jquery file upload [plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). I am able to upload some file form my desktop (as in the demo on the related site), but when I have to validate my form, I get an empty file `input`. How can it be ?

I have somthing like

```
<button class="add-on" type="button"><?php echo _('Add...') ?></button>
<input type="file" class="input-file-upload" name="image" size="40" />
```

On click on the `button`, I add a file, then I launch the upload with

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
                    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
                    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
                    url: 'myurl',
                    progressall: function (e, data) {
                        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                        $('#progress .bar').css(
                            'width',
                            progress + '%'
                        );
                    }
                });
```

At the end of this upload from my desktop, I submit with a `button type="submit"`.

Comment: How and when do you validate your form?

Comment: @SebastianG If you take the `http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/` as an example. I add a file, start upload, and when finished, I submit the form

Comment: @Newben The upload is some kind of Ajax-based form submit. How do you submit the form afterwards? For what reason? I don't see a submit button there.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the two basic options where you can check if the input control has file or not and 
then proceed with what you want to do.

```
.bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) 
{
/*Check here whether the user selected file or not*/
})
.bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) 
{
 /*Check here whether the user selected file or not before submitting your form*/
})
```